# Is there any rule for pronouncing the suffix "-less"

Tags: pronunciation

I found that the suffix "-less" can have different pronunciations, for example:

**borderless   /ˈbɔːdələs/

hopeless   /ˈhəʊplɪs/

helpless     /ˈhɛlplɛs/**

So, is there any rule for the pronunciation of this suffix?

Comment: It's not that the final consonant is enunciated differently *in those specific words* (the full OED gives just the **/ɪs/** ending for all three of your examples). It's just that *some speakers, in some contexts* reflect the standard pronunciation of the single-word form ***less*** in these "combined" forms. And *others* just reduce the vowel to a schwa.

Comment: Thank you, FumbleFingers. So, if I understand well, that's because people use the schwa sound /ə/.
I have another question. It's better for me (english learner) to pronounce the words with the sound /ɪs/ or to use the schwa sound /əs/ ?

Comment: It won't make much difference. The reason native speakers are so "variable" about this one is *they don't really care* (there's no real chance of the intended word being misheard and interpreted as something else), so they won't pay much if any attention. I suggest you ***plan*** on enunciating  **/ɪs/** - but don't try ***too*** hard. You'll probably find that once you settle in to a rapid speech delivery, it'll tend to become more "schwa-like" (get closer to **/əs/**). And *specifically*, DON'T make a conscious effort to fully articulate the "standalone" **/ɛs/** in such compound words.

Comment: I understand. 
Thank you very much, FumbleFingers.
Could you answer the question so that I can rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the final syllable is enunciated differently *in those specific words* (the full OED gives just the **/ɪs/** ending for all three of your examples).

It's just that *some speakers, in some contexts* will reflect the standard pronunciation of the single-word form ***less*** (**/ɛs/**) in these "combined" forms (especially if they're concentrating on the *written* form, rather than simply echoing back what they usually *hear* from others). And some people just reduce the vowel to a schwa / "neutral" vowel (**/əs/**) because it's "easier". But *most speakers in most contexts* will use **ɪs/** (as indicated by the full OED, and probably *most* other dictionaries).

One reason native speakers are so "variable" about this one is *they don't really care*. There's no real chance of the intended word being misheard and interpreted as something else, so they won't pay much if any attention to something that's essentially an irrelevant detail.

Comment: Sorry FumbleFingers. I voted your answer but 
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Oh, I'd forgotten about that restriction on new users! Does that also mean you can't "accept" the answer (I thought the ***asker*** also got rep points for accepting an answer). Anyway, I've given your question an upvote, which along with forthcoming votes from others should soon have you fully equipped with voting and commenting rights. :)

Comment: ...there you go! You've just got 5 points for upvoting, and another 2 for accepting. Nearly half-way there!